# Deduce absolute convergence of a sum in the integrand from finiteness of the integral

Tags: real-analysis, integration, functional-analysis, uniform-convergence, pointwise-convergence

Let $\Big ( p_i(u) : i \in \mathbb{N}, u \in [0, \infty) \Big )$ be a sequence of functions between $0$ and $1$. Suppose that these functions satisfy, for some given non-negative coefficients $c_i \geq 0$, $i \in \mathbb{N}$,
$$
\forall j \in \mathbb{N}, \quad p_{j}(t) = \int_{0}^t du \sum\limits_{i \in \mathbb{N}\\ i \neq j} c_i p_i(u) du.
$$

Do I have enough information to deuduce that the sum of the integrand is absolute convergent?

It is clear to me that the sum in the integrand must be at least point-wise convergent, since the integral is finite (it must be equal to $p_{j}(t)$), hence the integrand must be finite. But what about uniformity? From a text I read it seems that uniformity should also follow from the expression...